# stuck at the basic - get the launch up and running

Tags: php, macos, aptana

I am a new mac user and I'm trying to install my aptana now on my mac ... it's been years since I last did it on my windows and I'm stuck at basic:

I can't seem to get an external server working with Aptana Studio on Mac. I am using XAMPP, and I set the Base URL to http://localhost and the Document Root to my htdocs folder in XAMPP, but it keeps saying Launch URL is not defined.

at the Properties of my project I use a specific server with the same url - 
but when I try to run it says I cannot make a connection to my lokalhost.

Browser executable says: /Applications/Safari.app

am I overlooking the obvious here?
thanks for your help

Comment: Try spelling localhost correctly:  `localhost`  Your URL has it right, but I wanted to make sure it is correct for you, since your error mentions `lokalhost`.